# How to display a type alias instead of a parametric type in error messages

Tags: julia

I build a parametric type in julia:

```
type MyType{T}
    x::T
end
```

and for simplicity, I build a type alias for `Float64`:

```
typealias MT MyType{Float64}
```

I now deliberately cause an error involving `MT`. For example:

```
y1 = MyType(1.0)
y2 = MyType(2.0)
y1 + y2
```

will throw an error because `+` is not defined for `MyType`. The error message says:

```
`+` has no method matching +(::MyType{Float64}, ::MyType{Float64})
```

I would like it to say:

```
`+` has no method matching +(::MT, ::MT)
```

Why? Because real-world examples sometimes get quite a bit more complicated than this toy example, and one purpose of a type alias is to make a complicated specific instance of a parametric type easily recognisable. So it would be nice to also make it easily recognisable in error messages.

**What have I tried?** My best guess is that the error function calls the `string` function over a `DataType` in order to generate the appropriate strings in the error message. So it isn't obvious to me that I can extend the `string` function via multiple dispatch to specialise on my type alias, so I'm pretty much at a loss about where to go from here.

Comment: I don't think its possible for Julia to do it itself, because there could be multiple type-aliased. I believe your guess is correct too, and yes that seems like a dead end. Its not an unreasonable thing to desire though - I think a Github issue would be an appropriate forum for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to define an appropriate `show` method:

```
import Base.show
show(io::IO, ::Type{MT}) = print(io, "MT")
```

Your example then gives:

```
julia> y1 + y2
ERROR: `+` has no method matching +(::MT, ::MT)
```

Comment: I wonder if an alternate `typealias`, or perhaps a macro `@typealias` might do these steps automagically.

Comment: Brilliant. I was hoping it'd be something simple like that. Many thanks!

Comment: As of 1.6, this will happen automatically.